# How is this pointer null and not null at the same time?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm running into this strange issue. Basically I have a loop that loops forever, in the beginning of that loop I open a file, I write some stuff to the file, then at the end of the loop I close the file. Works fine for the first iteration of the loop but on the second iteration I get

```
*** glibc detected *** ./prog: double free or corruption (top):
```

I have narrowed this down to the `fclose(data)` line during the second iteration of the loop. Apparently this error happens when you are freeing something more than once but how is that possible in this code?

```
while(1)
{
    if (data == NULL)
    { 
        data = fopen(data_path, "w+");
    }

    /* do a bunch of stuff... */

    if (data != NULL)
    { 
        fclose(data);
    }
}
```

A stranger thing is that if I add the following line after `fclose(data)` the program runs just fine without any problems:

```
 data = NULL;
```

Can someone who is better versed in C than me please explain what's going on here?

Comment: Run your program with valgrind and it shall tell you automagically what is wrong with it.

Comment: Calling `fclose` on `data` does *not* make `data` into a NULL pointer; in fact, it does not (and cannot) change the value of `data` *at all*.  What it does is cause there no longer to be a FILE object at the memory location that `data` points to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

fclose does not make the file pointer NULL.
It Simply closes the file.
So in the second iteration the file is not opened because data is not NULL.

Comment: Ahh.. okay, that makes sense. But inside my main loop I'm writing to the file pointer several times using fprintf, shouldn't fprintf complain if I'm trying to write to a file pointer that's already closed?

Comment: You should check the return value of fprintf. Also, fprintf doesn't know if the file has closed. It simply tries to dump the characters to the file pointer.